# Project File Import

Tags: android, import, adt, dalvik, projects-and-solutions

I recently bought a new MacBook Pro and imported a couple of project files from the old laptop. Today I attempted to run an app on my device, but the project would not show in the run configurations window.I imported the file again, and got the project to show, but now I get the following error when trying to run on my device:

```
    [2014-01-06 21:04:04 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define                Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson$OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
    [2014-01-06 21:04:04 - Verbatim] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/Watson$OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
```

I believe I made a mistake in the way I transferred files over from the old laptop, as well as how I imported the project into the ADT. I have no clue what the above error means and have no idea how to begin fixing it. Perhaps someone can enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have multiple versions of the same projects. Dex files are what really runs Android (converted from Java, thankfully done automatically)
Try deleting all of the same projects in the adt (make sure to back that one project up just in case). Try going to the workspace folder and make sure to have only one version of it, then import it. Hope it helps